# uncaught error during route navigation:Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am getting this error when trying to navigate between pages either through links or buttons, the error seems to be raised specifically at boundRouteGuard function in vue-router.js source file which seems that the `guard` parameter  passed to the function is undefined

```
function bindGuard (guard, instance) {
  if (instance) {
    return function boundRouteGuard () {
     return guard.apply(instance, arguments)
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my route file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import i18n from './../plugins/i18n.plugin'
import routes from './routes'
const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',
 base: process.env.BASE_URL,
 routes,
 linkActiveClass: 'current',
 linkExactActiveClass: 'exact-current'
})
Vue.use(VueRouter);

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  function redirectToLogin () {
    next({ name: 'login', query: { redirectFrom: to.fullPath } })
  }



 // If this isn't an initial page load...
 if (from.name !== null) {
  NProgress.start()
 }


 document.title = to.meta.title || i18n.t('app.title')

 const authRequired = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.authRequired)
 const token = localStorage.getItem('tokenData')

 if (authRequired && !token && to.name !== 'login') {
   redirectToLogin()
 } else {
  console.log(to.path)
  next()
 }
})


// When each route is finished evaluating...
router.afterEach(() => {
 // Complete the animation of the route progress bar.
 NProgress.done()
})

export default router
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  If you would like, post a reproducible example of the error at https://codesandbox.io